# Read hive table from R using ORCH

Tags: r, oracle, hadoop, hive

In Oracle Big Data Appliance we use Oracle R distribution, our Hadoop is Kerberos safe. First of all I am taking a ticket from kerberos

```
R>   system("echo **[myPass]** | kinit **[myUser]**")
```

I am using Oracle R distribution in my cluster. So I installed the package ORCH in R. And setting my Ore type to Hive.

```
R>   library("ORCH")
R>   ore.connect(type="HIVE")
```

After that, I want to read a dimensions simple table which located in hive

```
R>   dim(ore.get(name = "a_trial", schema = "tgar"))
```

Then I am getting the error below.

> Error in get(name, envir = env) : object 'a_trial' not found

Actually a_trial table is exist in tgar schema. Assuming that the table has a problem, I'm trying a simple query like that

```
R> ore.sync(query = c("QUERY1" = "SHOW DATABASES"))
```

error is like that

> Error: HIVE command failed

What am I doing wrong? How can I connect hive from R via ORCH library successfully?

Comment: I changed my simple query example :) @SamsonScharfrichter

Comment: I don't know anything about R in general, nor about that bizarre Oracle extension in particular, but their documentation states that `ore.attach()` is necessary to *"...Attach the current envt. into search path of R"*

Comment: I tried that also. but nothing changed @SamsonScharfrichter

Answer (score 1):

we had the same problem some time ago.
We solved the problem passing the realm into the schema parameter, like this:

```
ore.connect(user="USERNAME", password="PASSWORD", host="HOSTNAME", schema="SCHEMA_NAME;principal=REALM", type="HIVE"),
```

where REALM is taken from hive-conf.xml.
Once you have a working connection, you may explicitly change the schema, e.g.:

```
ore.sync(schema="SCHEMA_NAME", table="TABLE_NAME")
```

Comment: when I pass schema property in ore.connect function I get the error : unused argument (schema = "TGAR;principal=REALM") or unused argument (schema = "TGAR"). Doesn't make sense adding REALM as a value. @Gianluca My full script is sth like that  ore.connect(user = "xx", password="yyy", host="helloKitty", schema="TGAR;principal=REALM", type="HIVE" )